# Echo a PHP function with condition inside HTML tag using concatenation

Tags: php, html, css, function, concatenation

This is my first question.

I'm building a simple dynamic menu using `<li>`

I'm working on a PHP based CMS (Kirby)

Kirby has predefined PHP functions (helpers)

I'm trying to output a `<li>` for each page on the website:

```
<li class='active'><a href='page1'></a></li>
<li><a href='page2'></a></li>
<li><a href='page3'></a></li>
...
```

Im using a PHP function `e($condition, $value)` to style the menu item only if that page `isOpen()`

```
// I need help here
<?php 
    foreach ($pages->visible() as $p): 
    echo "<li" . e($p->isOpen(), ' class="active"') . "><a href='" . $p->url() . "'></a></li>";
    endforeach; 
?>
```

The function is working but the css part `class="active"` is printing OUTSIDE the `<li>` on the final code

```
class="active"
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
```

I had this previous code that worked fine, but since i'm using `display: inline-block` the menu had spaces betwes each block, since the following code was placing each `<li>`in a new line.

```
// This code works
<?php foreach($pages->visible() as $p): ?>
<li <?php e($p->isOpen(), ' class="active"') ?> ><a href="<?php echo $p->url() ?>"></a></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

The reason i'm rewrinting the code is to remove the white space between the `inline: block`elements.

I'm failing to concatenate the string in a way that the function works and print its results inside the `<li>`tag.

I've searched here and also have read lots of Docs in php.net but nothing worked to me, I'm struggling with this for 2 days.

I'm expecting to learn better how and when to use concatenation and string operators.

Comment: _“The reason i'm rewrinting the code is to remove the white space”_ – well then simply do that, and leave the other stuff untouched. `… ?><li … a></li><?php …`

Comment: You should post the contents of your `e` function. But either way, you're using `echo` inside that function, where you should be using `return` of the value you're trying to print.

Comment: The output you posted makes it look like your `e` function is echoing the value instead of returning it, like @sjagr suggests.

Comment: It should be noted that if it's the Kirby CMS that has written this function and not you - it's time to stop using that CMS. EDIT: Seems that `e` is actually a desired behaviour for KirbyCMS, and it's just being used wrong. Huzzah!

Comment: @sjagr I do not disagree, however it would be helpful to elaborate exactly why  it is time to stop using Kirby

Comment: @CBroe Writing it all inline worked fine too, thank you.

Comment: @sjagr Exactly the answer that solved my problem while keeping my markup. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Kirby's e() function already has the echo in the routine, instead of just simply returning the value.

http://getkirby.com/docs/cheatsheet/helpers/e

If you were to change your output loop to something more like this, echoing separately, you'll get the results in the desired order:

```
foreach($pages->visible() as $p) 
{
    echo "<li";
    e($p->isOpen(), ' class="active"');
    echo "> and the rest of your line </li>";
}
```

That said, perhaps using e() isn't the most elegant in this case. Maybe try the r() function instead:

http://getkirby.com/docs/cheatsheet/helpers/r

```
foreach($pages->visible() as $p)
{
    echo "<li ".r($p->isOpen(), ' class="active"').">more text</li>";
}
```

Comment: Just replacing the e() with r() made everything work fine! Thank you!